# Magento 2 Redirect and display error in all admin page after click on "sign in"

Tags: magento2, admin, login, magento2.4

I am trying to login in admin but it display "There has been an error processing your request".

It generate error in like **"Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\m24\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php on line 591"**

Also try to create new user and login but that solution is not working in my case. Note that I am using magento 2.4. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @DianaBotean PHP version 7.4.8

Comment: can you check if you have the sodium extension installed and enabled? `php -i | grep -i libsodium` or `php -i | grep "sodium"`

Comment: Yes, extension is enabled.

Comment: as per Magento system requirements, it says that *Magento supports PHP 7.4.0.*. can you try maybe with 7.4.0 and see if it helps? and also try removing the existing admin user and recreating it afterwards.

Comment: It working fine before 2 days with PHP 7.4.8. after that don't know what happened and it stop working.

Comment: any uogrades? code changes in the meantime?

Comment: Not change in file.But after installation of 2.4.2 , 2.4.0 stop working.